# Fruity love philter knobs don't work and are dimmed

Tags: fl-studio

Ever since something happened (I forget what happened, sorry D:), whenever I try to add a Fruity Love Philter to a channel, the knobs are dimmed and "locked":

[image]

When I try to change / drag them, they animate, like the knob spins, but the change doesn't take effect. I've restarted FL and my computer. What happened, and how do I fix this?

EDIT: Just found out if I choose a preset (top-left arrow, Presets) it works, but I still can't change the knobs after that. They are locked to their initial position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops...
Just realized I had selected the second tab, so this is expected. I guess if you select a tab, like the second, that tab will stay opened even if you restart.